# confusion about relative URLs and trailing slash

Tags: url, relative-url

In the MDN documentation about URL, the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL#examples_of_relative_urls) of relative path appears to conflict with [RFC's definition](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-5.2.3) of how to merge a relative path.

A screenshot of the example presented in MDN docs:

[image]

RFC 3986 states:

> return a string consisting of the reference’s path component appended to all but the last segment of the base URI’s path (i.e., excluding any characters after the right-most “/” in the base URI path, or excluding the entire base URI path if it does not contain any “/” characters).

According to RFC 3986 , the correct full URL should be

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Skills/Infrastructure/Understanding_URLs
```

instead of

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Skills/Infrastructure/Understanding_URLs
```

So what's the answer here?